# React Modern Chart (SharePoint Framework) - Can't Retrieve Managed Metadata Value

Tags: spfx-webparts, chart-web-part

Anyone use React-Modern-Chart to retrieve Managed Metadata Fields and facing a problem that the label or value can't be displayed and showing 'object object'.

Please help.
Thanks.

Cheers,
VTEC[image]

Comment: Hello, [object Object] is the default to String representation of an object in JavaScript. Have you checked what the [object Object] values contain. Logging them in browser with console.log(object) might help. Looks like these you need to refer to the object.property to get the label/ value.

Comment: No issue for other type of fields except managed metadata field. It's a taxanomy field and diff with other type of field to retrieve the value. just wondering on how to get the value of this managed metadata field in javascript (SPFx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create a personalized navigation of a SharePoint site, I linked the pages of this site with the terms of a termset created for this purpose, thanks to an MMS field added in the site pages list. Maybe this case can help you. I will explain in the following how I did it.

Ths MMS field has this structure:

```
mms: {
    label: string;
    termGuid: string; 
    wssId: any; 
  }
```

In my case, I retrieve the contents of the MMS field like this:

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";

var mms = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Site Pages").items.select("MMS").getAll();
```

*MMS* is the name of the column in which the term is recorded:

[image]

You can take a look at the documentation for @pnp/sp/items v1 [here](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/v1/sp/docs/items/). I used v1 because the new version of PnPjs has removed sp-taxonomy librarie. See [here](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/transition-guide/#drop-client-svc-and-sp-taxonomy-libraries).

So to access the terms of the taxonomy, the sp-taxonomy library is used as follows:

```
import { 
  taxonomy, 
  ITermStore,
  ITerm,
  ITermData
} from '@pnp/sp-taxonomy'; 

const store = taxonomy.termStores.usingCaching().getById("store-id"); 
const termSet = store.usingCaching().getTermSetById("termset-id"); 
const select = ['IsRoot', 'Labels', 'TermsCount', 'Id', 'Name', 'Parent']; 
const terms = await termSet.terms.select(...select).usingCaching().get();
```

Here I got the fields *IsRoot*, *Labels*, *TermsCount*, *Id*, *Name* and *Parent* from all terms of the termset.

All that remains now is to make the link between the termset terms and the MMS field that contains the term associated with the pages to create the navigation of the site.

I plan to write a blog post to describe this solution if it helped and if it suits your needs consider upvoting.

Comment: It's quite useful if you are willing to write the step by step on how to retrieve the taxanomy field value and name in blog. Please share the blog link once you have done.